# Memory leak when using Pivot's ItemsSource property via binding (+ repro code)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application, a user uses a pivot like a book, he flips pivot items until he hits the last, then I remove existing pivot items and load new ones. This is all done by simply pointing the `Pivot.ItemsSource` property to a new collection of items.

I've noticed that overtime the memory consumption increases and is never getting lower. It seems that Pivot's VisualTree is not getting garbage collected.

I've created a sample application to demonstrate the problem (this is a WP8 app):

Steps to reproduce:

- Launch App
- Navigate to Page1
- Click the Load More Button a couple of times.

  (At a time it loads 100 items which of course is not what I do in a real
     application, but    it demonstrates clearly how the memory
     consumption gets higher and higher each time and is not cleared even if navigated back)

I'd be grateful for any tips or suggestions to lower the memory, as the way it is, inevitably the app is going to crash if it's going to be used this way for a long enough time.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
...
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Page1.xaml">
    Page1
</HyperlinkButton>
...
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
    //...
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        timer.Tick += delegate
                          {
                              Debug.WriteLine("{0:f} MB, {1:f} MB",
                                              DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage/(1024.0*1024),
                                              DeviceStatus.ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage/(1024.0*1024));
                          };
        timer.Start();
    }
    //...
```

**Page1.xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <StackPanel>
                  <phone:Pivot x:Name="pivot1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <!--Pivot item one-->
                    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:Pivot>
                <Button Click="Load_More">Load More</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

**Page1.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<int> _items;
        public List<int> Items
        {
            get
            {
                if (_items == null)
                {
                    _items = new List<int>();
                }
                return _items;
            }

            set
            {
                _items = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Load_More(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var lst = new List<int>();
            //100 new items just for demonstration, in reality i won't have more than 6 new items
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                lst.Add(i);
            }
            pivot1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Items=lst;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

      ~Page1()
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("Page1 GC");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the Pivot control leaks, as demonstrated by using the Panorama control instead.
Replacing your stack panel with this (I didn't change the control's name) doesn't leak. (Memory gets reclaimed around 50 megs)

```
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="Load_More">Load More</Button>
            <phone:Panorama x:Name="pivot1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <phone:PanoramaItem></phone:PanoramaItem>
            </phone:Panorama>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi, seems so. The leak is not present on WP7 though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to keep reusing the same collection of items instead of creating new collections. When you need to change it, clear the collection and then repopulate it.  The collection could reside in App global space for example:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static List<int> GlobalList;
...
    }
```

Initialize it in the MainPage constructor and then reference it via `App.GlobalList`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Perhaps you can try this solution: [Windows Phone 8: LongListSelector Memory Leak](http://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/windows-phone-8-longlistselector-memory-leak/)

Try to clean those dependency properties before closing your page.

#### Solution 2

Try to use `OservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` for binding `Itemsource`. Bind a `List<T>` to a `Itemsource` may cause memory leak due to WPF design.

[A memory leak may occur when you use data binding in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us)